# Slicing assignment, shallow/deep copy

Tags: python, slice, deep-copy, shallow-copy

So, I understand this:

```
a_list = [1,2,3]
b_list = [5,6,7]
a_list.append(b_list)
```

a_list is currently `[1,2,3, [5,6,7]]`

```
c_list = a_list[:]
b_list[0] = 1000
print(a_list, c_list)
```

a_list is `[1,2,3,[1000,6,7]]`

c_list is `[1,2,3,[1000,6,7]]`

`a_list` and `c_list` are both changed because when `b_list` was appended to `a_list`, `b_list` was a reference to `[5,6,7]`, and any change to `b_list` shows change in `a_list` and `c_list`. That's good.

The problem is when you have:

```
a_list = [1, 2, [1,5,0]]
b_list = a_list[:]
a_list[2][1] = 90000
print(a_list, b_list)
```

`a_list` is `[1, 2, [1, 90000, 0]]` and `b_list` is `[1, 2, [1, 90000, 0]]`.

Why did `b_list` change? `b_list` is a shallow copy of `a_list` that, if it had references, it would copy the references, not the actual objects. 
However, `a_list` has no references to copy; it is an exact value, a list of numbers, and `b_list` should not change if some value in a_list changed since they are completely different, `b_list` is not pointing to `a_list` through assignment.

Comment: The nested list is *still a reference*. Variables are named references, indices in a list are numbered references.

Comment: A shallow copy is a new list whose elements are the same as the elements of the original list (*not* copies of those elements).  If you want to recursively copy the elements, use `copy.deepcopy`.

Answer (score 1):

**Everything** in Python is a reference. List indices are just references, just like names (variables).

So `a_list[2]` is a reference to a list object, just like `a_list[0]` is a reference to an integer object. You created a shallow copy of `a_list`, meaning that all 3 references were copied to a new list object.

Ergo, `b_list[2]` references the same object as `a_list[2]`, another list object. modifying that list object via `a_list[2]` or `b_list[2]` will make the change visible via either.

If you need to have referenced objects copied too, create a deep copy. You could use `copy.deepcopy()` to recursively copy everything, or use a list comprehension to create shallow copies of directly nested lists only.